# What is the equivalent MVC code for ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my MVC C# project (NOT THE CORE) i used this successfully:

Index.cshtml:

```
 <script>
 @{
 var ListVar = Model.TimeToolDataList;
//TimeToolDataList (*it's an object list, ex: NAME = string, VALUE = int)

  var SerializedList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ListVar);
  }//razer code in the script tag ^ by the @{} wrapper


  var SerializedListRefined = JSON.parse('"@SerializedList"');
  var FinalList = JSON.parse(htmlDecode(SerializedListRefined));</script>
```

great!!! i can console.log the list and 'see' it's contents, what is the equivalent of this code for ASP.NET CORE project? because when i copy/pasted *along with all the other stuff, it wont run!!!

This cant be used: `JavaScriptSerializer()`
This cant be used either: `JSON.parse(htmlDecode(SerializedListRefined));`

Update, instead of `JavaScriptSerializer()` , this worked:

```
var jsonStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ListVar);
```

^under `@using System.Text.Json;`

when running, the console on the browser gives me an 'Uncaught ReferenceError: htmlDecode is not defined' error

Comment: What do you mean it "won't run"? What's preventing you from running it? Are you getting an exception? Please provide enough detail in your questions so that we can actually help.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` should not be used for Json serialization ever.  This is why .NET Core does not even contain this class.  Depending on what version of .NET Core you are running you should use Json.NET or the `System.Text.Json` stuff

Comment: yes the System.Text.Json helped with the backend, how do i get to the final part? @maccettura

Comment: @Adan you have a mix of Javascript and C# in your question and you have not formatted it in a way that is clear.  Is the `'Uncaught ReferenceError: htmlDecode is not defined'` error an exception?  A console error in the browser?  You need to seriously edit your question

Comment: @maccettura ok i did some edits, how's it looking?

Comment: `htmlDecode()` needs to be defined in your javascript somewhere, so if that function does not exist then you cant call it obviously

Comment: @maccettura htmlDecode() is built in, there's no defenition in the working page

Comment: @Adan `htmlDecode()` is built in where?  Thats not an out of the box JS function as far as I know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212801/discussion-between-adan-and-maccettura).

Comment: Also, your problem is now strictly JS related.  So I would recommend asking a new (and clearer) question and include the relevant tag(s) (javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like the next
to deserialize the object correclty you have to use `@HtmlRaw` just assuming `ListVar` is your `Model`/`Object` (the object comming from the c# controller)

you can do the next :

`var jsoninJS = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Listvar));`

that gives you in your `var jsoninJS` the object that you can print with `Console.log(jsoninJS)` in javascript.

if you include 
`@using System.Web` you can also decode with C#

using `@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)`
but you should decode/encode on you print the data, not anywhere else.